# How to have a sum of numbers so that sum(4) would do 1+2+3+4

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

```
-module(test).
-export([sum/1]).

sum([]) -> 0;
sum([X|Xs]) -> X + sum(Xs)
```

This is what I have done so far though it only sums the numbers within a list like `test:sum([1,2,3,4])`

but I want it so that its like `test:sum(4)` will output 1+2...+n

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

This function you have provided will sum values in list, but if you want to "overload" this function to also support integers then you can write:

```erlang
-module(test).
-export([sum/1]).

sum([]) -> 0;
sum([X|Xs]) -> X + sum(Xs);

sum(0) -> 0;
sum(N) when is_integer(N) -> (N * (N + 1)) div 2.
```

This uses pattern matching to check type of the argument, and then pick proper "version" of the function to evaluate.

Comment: (N * (N + 1)) div 2 will be right... [http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html]

Answer (score 2):

Simple one line example with using Erlang functions:

```erlang
sum(N) -> lists:sum(lists:seq(1, N)).
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I want it so that its like test:sum(4) will output 1+2...+n

Here's a recursive solution:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

sum(0) ->
    0;
sum(X) ->
    X + sum(X-1).
```

In the shell:

```
3> my:sum(1).
1
4> my:sum(2).
3
5> my:sum(3).
6
6> my:sum(4).
10
7> my:sum(5).
15
```

Note that if you call `sum/1` with a negative number, `sum/1` will recurse forever and eventually crash the shell, so you can add a guard to accept only positive numbers.  Then if you call `sum/1` with a negative number, you will get a `function_clause` error instead, which you get when: *No matching function clause is found when evaluating a function call.*  Of course, you can also define another function clause that will handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

using tail recursion
here is the code below:

```
% function entry
sum(N) -> sum(N,0);

sum(0,Acc) -> Acc;
sum(N,Acc) -> sum(N-1,Acc+N).
```